# How do I trigger a user control's button click event?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, user-controls

In my web application, I have a user control that has some buttons in it. On another page, I want to load in that control and program what happens when the buttons are clicked. How do I trigger the click event of the button inside my user control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have this in your user control code:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button" Text="Button" runat="server" />


Public Class UserControl

  Public Event ButtonClick()

  Private Sub button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) handles Button.Click
    Raise Event ButtonClick()
  End Sub

End Class
```

Then on the page you want to load the user control on you could call the button's click event like this:

```
<UC:Button ID="UCButton" runat="server" />


Private Sub UCButton_Click() Handles UCButton.ButtonClick
  'write your code here
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you answer your own question or is this part of your original question?

Comment: @Win I was looking for a solution to this problem, but couldn't find one. I ended up figuring it out and wanted to share my findings.

Comment: Awesome. Please mark it as ***Answer***, so it will help others who have similar issue.

Comment: @Win I tried to mark this as answer when I posted it, but got a notification that said "You can mark this as answer in 2 days". So I am waiting until it is enabled.